# Source code for Logo in Z80 assembly

Tags: z80, logo-language

I am looking for a source code for Logo written in Z80 assembly (the complete language, not only the turtle part). I found the disassembly of Terrapin Logo for Apple 2e but it is 6502. Ideally, it would fit in 16K. I would like something in the style of 8KLisp (https://github.com/jonruttan/8k-lisp). Thanks in advance

Comment: There are [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)#Implementations) for the TRS-80 and the Armstrad CPC, so that's where I'd start hunting for the source. Note that the graphics will always be system-specific. You could also build on the Lisp implementations.

Comment: There's also an implementation for the Sinclair ZX Spectrum.

Comment: I definitely remember using Dr. Logo on CPC 6128. It was distributed on the CP/M+ (CP/M 3) floppy disks. Amstrad allowed redistribution of their ROMs and disassembly listings are easy to find on the net, I don't know about parts on the CP/M floppy disks. Depending on your juridiction, you may have the formal right to disassemble/trace and study it.

Comment: "diisassembly listings are easy to find on the net" Idi not find it. Can you give links explicitely? Thanks in advance.

Comment: DR Logo was written in (BDS) C, and most of the source isn't in the DR archives. Can only find binaries, but Mattel Aquarius Logo is very small. Sinclair "Logo 1" is larger, but was written by LCSI/SOLI, "the" Logo developers. There was also a version for the Coleco Adam. No sources to any of these, sadly, so some hard disassembly ahead

Comment: Here's something to help you dig further: http://recursostic.educacion.es/secundaria/edad/4esotecnologia/quincena12/pdf/Logo_TreeProject.pdf

Comment: @German Your link does not work. Please, upload it in archive.org to enable anybody to access it.

Comment: yes it works. the doc is not mine, it's all over the web. try: https://neoparaiso.com/logo/documentos/LogoTreeProject.pdf or just search for logotreeproject.pdf

Comment: There is source for the 16-bit 8086 version of DRLOGO at http://www.cpm.z80.de/source.html

Comment: @German no I doesn't, at least for me, it's not working

Comment: http://www.edtechpolicy.org/cyberk12ARCHIVE/Resources/Microworlds/LogoTreeProject.pdf

Comment: There are three versions of Amstrad LOGO that I know of: v1.1 for the CPC, v2.0 for the CPC and v2.0 for the PCW. Unusually v1.1 is split - the first 32k are in a .COM file on the CP/M 2 boot disc and the last 8k is in the AMSDOS ROM. I haven't seen full disassemblies of any of them.

Comment: Why do you need the source?

Answer (score 0):

DR LOGO was released for Z80 and made available for the Tatung Einstein. I played with it briefly at the time, but was more interested in Z80 BBC BASIC that also shipped with the machine.

I can't find a link to a download of the DR LOGO disk image, but someone somewhere must have one. Here's a [page full of Tatung manuals](http://www.tatungeinstein.co.uk/front/mans.htm) including the one for DR LOGO. If you can find a disk image, maybe you can grab the executable and disassemble it.